# NHibernate Non-static method requires a target error message solution

Tags: nhibernate, reflection, fluent-nhibernate

I was getting this error message below from NHibernate.  I searched and did not find a clear solution to this error.  I stumbled upon a solution and thought I would share.  My problem turned out to be I needed to define a default constructor for the class (one that accepts no parameters):

```
public class Staff : Entity, IStaff
{
    public virtual int StaffId { get; set; }

    protected virtual internal Case Case { get; set; }

    protected virtual internal Person Person { get; set; }

    protected Staff() {}  // Define this constructor for NHibernate

    public Staff(Person person)
    {
        Person = person;
    }
}
```

Looking back, my problem started when I added the constructor to the class that accepted a Person parameter.  C# defines a default constructor, but only when you do not define any constructors.  Once you define a constructor you have to explicitly define the default constructor:

*If a class **does not** have a constructor, a default constructor is automatically generated and default values are used to initialize the object fields.*
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6sa6h87.aspx

I discovered this because I had a similar class that worked and I had defined a default constructor for that one because I needed one with no parameters in my code.

Error Stack Trace:

```
System.Reflection.TargetException occurred
  Message=**Non-static method requires a target**...
  Source=mscorlib

NHibernate.PropertyAccessException occurred
   Message=**could not set a property value by reflection setter** of
  *YourClassPropertyNameHere* ...
  Source=NHibernate
  StackTrace:
     at NHibernate.Properties.BasicPropertyAccessor.BasicSetter.Set(Object target, Object value)
```

Comment: It is OK to post a [problem and an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to). Maybe you could split up your post in a problem description and post the answer yourself and accept it (I think you can do that 15 hours later or so). Your question will appear as "answered" in searches.